# I want to share link to whatsapp from my android app

Tags: android, communication, whatsapp

I turn a website into android app with the help of WebView and I want to share my product link to WhatsApp but every time I click on button to share on WhatsApp it is showing error in android app but working fine on website[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR4VW.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.zidsworld.com/android-development/how-to-fix-unknown-url-scheme-in-android-webview) may help you out. While I cannot see your code to be sure, it seems that you have the correct WhatsApp:// url prefix, but may need to add a try/catch method or some sort of url scheme handler.